# A Lebesgue integral and measure theory problem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be a non negative measurable fuction on $\mathbb R $ such that $ \int f < \infty $ Prove that for every $ \epsilon $>0 there exists a measurable set $E$ such that $m(E) <\infty $ and $ \int_E f $ > $ \int f - \epsilon $
 I found tried using the Monotone convergence theorem and wasn't sure on how to approach it

Any help would be welcome

Answer (score 1):

Your idea was correct. Use the monotone convergence theorem on $f_n := f \cdot \chi_{B_n(0)}$, where $B_n (0)$ is the ball of radius $n$ around the origin.

EDIT: You probably mean such that $\int_E f > -\varepsilon + \int f$.

Comment: yes it was edited, thanks! Can you please tell how to get the specified set E though

Comment: $E = B_n(0)$ for $n$ so large that the desired inequality holds. Existence of such an $n$ follows by monotone (or by dominated) convergence.

Comment: Thanks! I got it since $f_n$ pointwise converges to f we can Monotone convergence and then use the definition of the limit and get the specific n right? Is  ∫f<∞ used anywhere in it?

Comment: Yes, because if $\int f = \infty$, then from $\int f_n \rightarrow \int f = \infty$ you can NOT conclude that $\int f - \int f_n < \varepsilon$ for large $n$.